# Launching IE 9 64bit using selenium grid

Tags: selenium-rc

I want to use IE 9 64 bit with selenium grid but when i start a new rc client with environment *iexplore it opens a 32 bit version of ie. So I want to know how to run my test cases on 64bit version of IE.

Answer (score 0):

Use "*iexplore C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" i think